# How do I pass a message from a Safari Extension popover to the global page?

Tags: popover, safari-extension

I am currently building a Safari Extension. I have a simple popover page with 3 buttons. On clicking those buttons, I need to perform some actions on the Global Page that involves manipulating localStorage and a couple of other things.

I can't seem to find any way to dispatch a message from the popover to the global page. There seem to be a heap of topics on dispatching from a popover to a content script, but nothing to the global page.

It's probably insanely simple and I am just missing something. Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to use message passing between a popover and the global page. They share the `safari.extension` object, so you can access either one's context from the other.

From a popover, you can access the global page's functions and other objects through `safari.extension.globalPage.contentWindow`. For example, if you have a function `foo` in the global page, you can call it from the popover with `safari.extension.globalPage.contentWindow.foo()`.

From the global page, you can access a popover's objects through `safari.extension.popovers[i].contentWindow`, where `i` is the popover's index.

Incidentally, popovers and the global page share the same `localStorage` object, so there's no need to use, for example, `safari.extension.globalPage.contentWindow.localStorage` from a popover; `localStorage` by itself will access the same store the global page uses.

Comment: I have a function getTimeline in global page. When I try  to access it form popover page using safari.extension.globalPage.contentWindow.getTimeStamp getting below error "TypeError: safari.extension.globalPage.contentWindow.getTimeStamp is not a function. (In 'safari.extension.globalPage.contentWindow.getTimeStamp()', 'safari.extension.globalPage.contentWindow.getTimeStamp' is undefined)"

Comment: Is it `getTimeline` or `getTimeStamp`?